# Bootstrap navbar empty on IE9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I tried to use the bootstrap template to generate a navbar on my aspnet mvc application.

Everything works fine on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE my menu is transparent :

[image]

I checked, I have the `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the begining of my layout.
I also tried `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

I tried to play with the F12 menu and compatibility mode, without success.

Any other clue ?

Thanks

Edit: here is the generated code :

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
                <title>Test &bull; Home</title>

                <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                <link href="toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
                <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
                <script src="angular.js"></script>
                <script src="angular-resource.js"></script>
                <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
                <script src="toastr.js"></script>

                <!--[if lt IE 9]> HTML5Shiv
                <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
                <![endif]--> 

            </head>

            <body style="padding: 40px;">
                <div class="container">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Test</a>
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-divider"></li> 
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="/Page1/">Page1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Page2/">Page2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Page3/">Page3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/Page4/">Page4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
                </div>
            </body>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link or the relevant code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also had the similar problem in IE9 as I started to work on a new project. Looking through the browser support section in http://getbootstrap.com, you need to add respond.js in the IE code block and also need to make sure it works from IE 9 and older browsers.

So the [if IE] block should look something like this.

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Notice the "lte" in the [if IE] block, which means IE <= 9, whereas "lt" meant IE < 9.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update:** I found an alternative solution to you problem. The bootstrap-theme.css used filter property on navbar which seems to making issues on IE9 and IE8. So you can just disable them by commenting them out. Then the dropdown menu will show up.

Look for 'filter' in .navbar & .navbar-inverse and disable them. This will ofcourse turn off gradients for IE9 and older.

Comment: Hi, I added the two references, I don't see any changes. I see the files are downloaded, but my menu is still empty. The browser support only states that the rounded corners are not supported by IE8. I don't see what's wrong here...

Comment: Oh.. my bad I didn't looked into your script links properly. I think its related to your jquery version 2.x which does not support IE 6-8. For IE older versions support, you need to use jquery 1.x versions, I think latest now is 1.10.2. Use that, hopefully it will be fixed.
[br]
Also for limited time, I uploaded a small test page in my server  http://www.abdmaster.com/abdtest/bootstrap3/navbar-fixed-top/

Its working fine to me on IE8-9. IE7 has some issues.

Comment: Hi, It's still weird: jquery 2.0 dropped the support for IE 6-7-8 ok, but my navbar doesn't work on IE9. Your script works.

Comment: the 'updated' answer should be promoted; it works perfectly. in more detail, I add following after link up the bootstrap 3.0 css/js. <style type="text/css"> .navbar { filter:none !important; } </style> save my day.

Comment: @lousiu, I disagree, `!important` is bad practice.
This issue has been fixed in the latest version off Bootstrap, your better off updating.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is not related to Jquery Version, but to a bug in IE and bootstrap.theme.css.

After comparing our two pages, I realized that you did not include that CSS, I narrowed my search and stumbled upon this issue : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10257

I commented the filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff8f8f8', GradientType=0); into navbar class, now it works !

Thanks for your help !